# How to restrict viewing properly in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a page in my application where the in the HTML, I have the following codes:

`{% if job.owner == user.username or user.username == 'admin' %}`

So this means that the logged in user can view job that he/she created  in the application and the admin user can view all the created jobs as admin is the master user.

I am trying to apply the same logic in django rest framework but it is not working. Now is just filtering `owner=request.user`. This works for only user can view their own created job, but it also affected the admin. Admin now cant view all the jobs due to the filtering. How do I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def jobs(request):
    job = Job.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    jobserializer = JobViewSeralizers(job, many = True)
    return Response(jobserializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using decorator or *if* try middelwares to restrict user access:

```py
# middelwares.py


from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = [
    '/',
    'api_url/',
]


class LoginMiddleWare:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or request.user != 'admin' and request.path not in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS:
            messages.error(request, 'You should login first!', 'warning')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And add it to settings:

```py
# settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    .
    .
    .

    'djangoProject_app.middlewares.LoginMiddleWare',
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not well verse in settings.py. Is it possible to explain to me how will this affect my browser side and API side?

Comment: Middleware is a lightweight plugin that is processed while requesting and executing responses. Middleware is used to perform a function in the program, these functions can be security, session, csrf protection, authentication and so on. Django provides you with a variety of internal intermediaries and also allows us to write our own intermediaries. 
Here is django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Thank for the explanation and link